# What Bigcomerce API call is used for to send ship notice?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm having trouble understanding the bigcomerece api documentation.

I cant find where it explains how to mark and order as shipped ,update with tracking number and initiate a customer ship notification email.

can someone help me with a link to this documentation?

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Create an Order Shipment:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders/shipments

There you can specify a "tracking_number" etc...